# Specified qdisc kind is unknown when using tc netem to emulate latency on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, linux, raspberry-pi-os

When I tried to emulate latency using tc. I get the following error on Raspberry Pi 3B+.

```
sudo tc qdisc replace dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
Error: Specified qdisc kind is unknown.
```

These are the current qdisc configuration.

```
sudo tc qdisc show
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev wlan0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc noqueue 0: dev docker0 root refcnt 2 
qdisc noqueue 0: dev flannel.1 root refcnt 2 
qdisc noqueue 0: dev cni0 root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev vethd05c54f6 root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev veth3928eef0 root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev vetha4aaed30 root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev vetha12c8686 root refcnt 2
qdisc noqueue 0: dev veth2d76978d root refcnt 2
```

OS details

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I want to emulate latency using Linux tc library, But I got the above error.

Comment: Similar question on Stackoverflow: [Linux fedora tc qdisc gets "Error: Specified qdisc not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64755248/427158)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the kernel package that provides the `sch_netem` kernel module.

You can search for it like this:

```
apt-file search sch_netem.ko
```

In case you don't find such a package you may need to check whether your kernel was built with SCH_NETEM support, e.g. via:

```
# grep netem /boot/config-$(uname -r) -i          
CONFIG_NET_SCH_NETEM=m
```

If your config doesn't contain such an entry you might need to look for an alternative kernel or compile your own kernel that enables the sch_netem kernel module.

After you installed that module you can check its availability like this:

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/sched/sch_netem.ko*
modinfo sch_netem
```